# Updating UI from events using asyc await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to understand how to update a UI from an event while using async/await pattern.
Below is the test code I am using on a WinForm app. I am not even sure this is the right way to go about it.  What is necessary to allow the pwe_StatusUpdate method to update the UI?  The cross-thread operation error is thrown there.

Thanks for reading.

```
 // calling code
    ProcessWithEvents pwe = new ProcessWithEvents();
    pwe.StatusUpdate += pwe_StatusUpdate;
    await pwe.Run();



 void pwe_StatusUpdate(string updateMsg)
    {
      // Error Here: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '_listBox_Output' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
      _listBox_Output.Items.Add(updateMsg);
    }
```

-

```
// Class with long running process and event    
public delegate void StatusUpdateHandler(string updateMsg);

 public class ProcessWithEvents
  {
    public event StatusUpdateHandler StatusUpdate;

    public async Task Run()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {

                    RaiseUpdateEvent(String.Format("Update {0}", i));

                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            });

        }

        private void RaiseUpdateEvent(string msg)
        {
        if (StatusUpdate != null)
            StatusUpdate(msg);
        }
   }
```

-

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[The `async` pattern has support for progress updates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

In short, your `async` method can take an `IProgress<T>`, and your calling code passes in an implementation of that interface (usually `Progress<T>`).

```
public class ProcessWithUpdates
{
  public async Task Run(IProgress<string> progress)
  {
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
        if (progress != null)
          progress.Report(String.Format("Update {0}", i));
        Thread.Sleep(500);
      }
    });
  }
}

// calling code
ProcessWithUpdates pwp = new ProcessWithUpdates();
await pwp.Run(new Progress<string>(pwp_StatusUpdate));
```

Comment: Is `ProcessWithProgress` in the `// calling code` section supposed to be `ProcessWithUpdates` instead?

Answer (score 8):

You should use `Invoke` method of `Control`. It executes some code in Control's thread. Also you can check `InvokeRequired` property to check if you need to  call `Invoke` method (it checks if the caller is on a different thread than the one the control was created on).

Simple example:

```
void SomeAsyncMethod()
{
    // Do some work             

    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
                DoUpdateUI();

            }
        ));
    }
    else
    {
        DoUpdateUI();
    }
}

void DoUpdateUI()
{
    // Your UI update code here
}
```

In some cases you should check the `IsHandleCreated` property of `Control` before calling `Invoke` method. If `IsHandleCreated` returns false then you need wait while Control's handle will be created

Comment: This works great as well as the progress suggession.  I am using both of approaches thanks very much.

Comment: You shouldn't implement this yourself when using the async pattern. `Progress<T>` is already executed on the SynchronizationContext that it was created on.

Comment: Simple solution. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

//Just declare a delegate like so

```
delegate void Add(string msg);
```

//Then declare the delegate method like so:

```
var add = new Add((msg) => {
   _listBox_Output.Items.Add(msg);
});
```

//Now just call the delegate:

```
void pwe_StatusUpdate(string updateMsg)
    {

      _listBox_Output.Invoke(add,updateMsg);
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is another example

```
async void DoExport()
{
    var rMsg = "";
    var t = await Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() => ExportAsMonthReport(LastMonth.Name, LastYear.Name, out rMsg));

    if (t)
    {
          BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
          {
               spinnerMain.Visible = false;
               menuItemMonth.Enabled = true;

               MetroMessageBox.Show(this, rMsg, "Export", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, 200);
          }));
   }
   else
   {
          BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
          {
               spinnerMain.Visible = false;
               menuItemMonth.Enabled = true;

               MetroMessageBox.Show(this, rMsg, "Export", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, 200);
          }));
    }
}
```