# how to get output in backgroundworker vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I use the following command to print adb output on textbox.text

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    TextBoxSamLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & Adb.ExecuteAdbCommand(Adb.FormAdbCommand("sideload", TextBoxsideload.Text)))
End Sub
```

does the job, but does not print the output and gets an error

How can we print the result on the textbox in the backgroundworker?

Comment: You cannot update the UI from a background thread. See this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45571728/3740093 (start from _**Accessing the UI thread**_)

Comment: Thankful
Solved using thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BackgroundWorker` has built-in functionality to allow you to access the UI thread, which is the whole point of its existence.

If you want to update the UI after the background work is completed then you handle the `RunWorkerCompleted` event and pass the data via the `e.Result` property.  If you want to update the UI during the background work then you call the `ReportProgress` method, pass the data via the `userState` parameter and handle the `ProgressChanged` event.  Both those events are raised on the UI thread.

[Click here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?471889-Using-the-BackgroundWorker-Component) for more information.