# addhandler ie.Documentcompleted , New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf DocumentCompleteIE) error

Tags: html, vb.net, internet-explorer

> AddHandler ie.DocumentCompleted gives DocumentCompleted' is not an
>   event of 'Object'

if I put ie.DocumentComplete I get

> Value of type 'WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler' cannot be
>   converted to 'DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler'

I followed several examples from the web and keep getting these errors. As if its not a code problem but that I'm missing a reference.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim myHTMLDoc As HtmlDocument
    Dim myhtmlelement As HtmlElementCollection
    Dim ie As WebBrowser
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ieurl As String
        ieurl = "http://companyurl.com"
        AddHandler ie.DocumentComplete, AddressOf DocumentCompleteIE
        ie.Navigate(ieurl)
        ie.Visible = True

    End Sub
    Private Sub DocumentCompleteIE(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("completed - " & ie.LocationURL)
        ie.Document.GetElementById("Login").SetAttribute("value", "x123456")
        ie.Document.GetElementById("Pwd").SetAttribute("value", "123456")
        ie.Document.GetElementById("Btn").InvokeMember("click")
    End Sub
End Class
```

If I start typing ie.Do (after addhandler) I see DocumentComplete as choice and 
not DocumentCompleted, which I find odd as the code I see everywhere on the net uses DocumentCompleted!

Comment: `DocumentCompleted` is related to the WebBrowser control. You're using the InternetExplorer ActiveX directly. See its documentation instead. Remove `New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler`.

Comment: What signifies that I'm using ActiveX directly?  The Imports SHDocVw? I see that I probably should use the WebBrowser control directly as the user doesn't need the IE page, just some data on it!

Comment: Not sure what you meant by remove New  WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf DocumentCompleteIE)!

Comment: 1) It means that you're using the [InternetExplorer object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v=vs.85)), not its managed WebBrowser control wrapper. You're mixing up methods that belogs to two different objects. The code you posted is just an attempt to auto-login, filling in and activating a WebForm. Use the WebBrowser control for this: much simpler, less baggage, same result. 2) `AddHandler [WebBrowser].DocumentCompleted, AddressOf DocumentCompleteIE`

Comment: Now I get this error on DocumentComplete  $exception {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} System.NullReferenceException

Comment: Changed the code to this!     [code]Dim ie As WebBrowser
    'Public Event DocumentCompleted As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ieurl As String
        ieurl = "http://companyurl.com"
        AddHandler ie.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf DocumentCompleteIE
        ie.Navigate(ieurl)
        ie.Visible = True

    End Sub
    Private Sub DocumentCompleteIE(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)[/code]

Comment: Please, don't add code in comments. Update your question if you have altered your code. Remove this thing:  `Public Event DocumentCompleted As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler`, it makes no sense. See [Auto Website Login: SetAttribute not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54030367/7444103).

Comment: Still getting eroor System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' on addhandler DocumentCompleteIE. My code matches the code from your suggested url! ( I think!)

Comment: `ie = New WebBrowser`. This: `Dim ie As WebBrowser` defines a Type, it doesn't create the instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use web browser control to load web page and fill the information and click the button than you can refer an example below.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'this is to load the site in web browser control.
        Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://localhost/login_form.html")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        ' this is to enter values in the textboxes and click the button in web browser control.
        Dim usernameTextBox As HtmlElement = Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("uname")
        usernameTextBox.InnerText = "x123456"

        Dim passwordTextBox As HtmlElement = Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("psw")
        passwordTextBox.InnerText = "123456"

        Me.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("signIn").InvokeMember("click")
    End Sub


End Class
```

Output:

[image]

You can also use **WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted** event to enter the values. I had also tested it and it is working fine. To use that you can simply copy the code from **Button3_Click** event and paste it in **WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted** event.

If you want to open IE browser and perform the same operation as above than you can refer code example below.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'this is to open IE browser and load the page and entering the values and click the button.
        Dim TheBrowser As Object = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        TheBrowser.Visible = True
        TheBrowser.Navigate("http://localhost/login_form.html")
        Do Until TheBrowser.ReadyState = 4 'PAGE_LOADED
        Loop
        TheBrowser.Document.GetElementById("uname").SetAttribute("value", "x123456")
        TheBrowser.Document.GetElementById("psw").SetAttribute("value", "123456")
        TheBrowser.Document.GetElementById("signIn").InvokeMember("click")
    End Sub
End Class
```